# Can I access the pre-installed hard disk of my laptop after booting the OS from a pendrive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems

I have an old Dell Vostro 1440, 2GB Ram, about 500GB HDD and an i3 processor. That's all I know about it. Using the system is a complete nightmare as it lags a lot. Yesterday I checked the Task Manager for the first time and saw that it said 90% memory used even though I had literally no apps/softwares running. I am thinking of upgrading it a bit by using an 8GB DDR3 RAM and using a 64GB pen drive to boot my OS faster than before.
Edit : I am thinking of using Ubuntu.

I use my laptop for coding in Java and some usual web surfing.

Will this upgrade fix the issue? And will I be able to use the system hard disk after I have booted the OS from a pen drive? I wish to use the system harddrive (the 500GB one) as a spare one where I'll store all the least important files, in case the disk fails.

I asked the same question at Stack Overflow but straight up got 2 downvotes. And no solutions.

Comment: I assume you got downvotes because some research would have shown to you that installing Windows 7 on an USB stick is not supported. In any way USB flash drives via USB 2.0/3.0 are usually not faster than a HDD. The flash in USB sticks is usually the slowest available on the market + the slow USB connection. Better buy a cheap SATA SSD and replace the internal HDD.

Comment: A SSD to replace your HDD would solve your performance problems and not cost much more than a 64GB USB drive. If you add more RAM,it should perform quite well. Check that the computer will support 8GB. If it was sold with only 2GB RAM, it may be running 32bit Windows.

Comment: @Robert no, he got downvotes on stack overflow, because that is a site about programming questions, where this is clearly not a programming question. When a new user does not check the help center to learn about what question is on-topic, people down-vote.

Comment: David Marshall , @Robert - I don't find SSD cheaper than a 64gb pen drive. The pen drive claims to provide upto 150mb/second .I don't want to play any games whatsoever. Just want to code and surf internet for any solutions of errors. I'll be using Ubuntu and getting 8gb ram. Do you still think the speed will be slow enough that it will be unusable  ?

Comment: The key words in pendrive specifications is "up to". You may get that for reading but write speed will be a fraction of that. Whether that is acceptable depends on what the system is doing. Typically USB sticks have much lower lifetimes than proper SSDs.

Comment: @Mokubai what is the expected lifetime  ?

Comment: Flash are good at sequential reads and writes - ie. when reading/writing rather large files sequentially. OS writes are random and parallelized and performance will be terrible. Depending on persistence implementation and your usage patterns the lifetime will be from a couple of weeks to a year or two. Long story short, running daily driver OS from a flash drive is not a good idea.

Comment: @gronostaj modern TLC flash is also perfect for random operations. More better (up to x100) and with higher endurance. Certainlz it reffers to SSD and not pen drives.

Comment: Hey  ! Its an update to my question .I bought a 64 gb pendrive and installed Ubuntu 19.10 on it , it has only USB2.0 ports still Ubuntu 19.10 is working like a charm . No lag whatsoever. So,to anyone on a tight budget i recommend installing OS on a pendrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to access your "system hard drive" But won't be able to use most of it due to compatibility issues.
Yes,the issue you described about, frequent lags will get fixed.
The only problem to consider is the life of USB.
It is really hard to say for how long it will work.
Also make sure to use USB drive which is reverse compatible with USB 2.0 incase you have to use it on a computer with USB2.0 ports only.